# http:// wrapper disabled but need to use query string

Tags: php

Some people disable the http wrapper for the include function. I need to use a query string when including a file, so I can't include it as a local file. Is it possible for me to override this setting? Can hosting companies make it impossible to override?

As long as I sanitise the input, I should be ok right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

no, you are never OK running the code you've got from a remote server. There are way too many ways to trick you into running something you don't expect. You'd better avoid it. If you are into adventures then you can try it with curl extension which is usually enabled on shared hosting. First get your text via curl 
http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-init.php
then eval it
http://php.net/manual/en/function.eval.php

Comment: Would SSI be of any use because all I want to do is include a script thats hosted on the same server but have to use full url because it uses a query string so that it know which record to retrieve from db